# Duplicate files copied in APK

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have this error

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.

com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK com/j256/ormlite/core/LICENSE.txt       
File1: ../.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.j256.ormlite/ormlite-core/4.48/e579bd2905d0399af5029aaaf9817d5fa0ca88a5/ormlite-core-4.48.jar  
File2: ../utils-lib/build/intermediates/bundles/default/classes.jar     
File3: ../networking-lib/build/intermediates/bundles/default/classes.jar
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add to build.gradle:

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude '**/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'pom.xml'
}
```

But you may exclude only `com/j256/ormlite/core/LICENSE.txt` instead all `LICENSE.txt` files

Comment: Thanks it works for me but another error has appeared 
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK pom.xml
   File1:../app/libs/signalr-client-sdk.jar
   File2: ../android-measurementslib1/build/intermediates/bundles/default/classes.jar

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
```